# What is the best way to insert into multiple related tables in postgresql with ariflow?

Tags: python, postgresql, airflow

I am creating data migration scripts using apache airflow, and I have stumbled upon this problem.

I have two tables ticket and a passenger. They look like this:

```
ticket:
--ticket_info,
--passenger_id

passenger:
--id
--passenger_info
```

As you can see, they are related through the fields `ticket.passenger_id=passenger.id`. The problem is that I have to insert into passengers first, then get inserted `passenger_id` with separate SQL, and then use them to insert into the `tickets` table.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: This doesn't really make sense to me. The join between these two tables is on the `ticket.passenger_id` and `passenger.id` fields. If you don't have the `passenger_id` when inserting into the `ticket` table then you can't simply retrieve it from the passenger table unless you join on some other fields?

Comment: Please post the table definitions for `ticket` and `passenger`  I have 2 questions: 1 -Is the column `passenger.id` an auto-incrementing column. 2 - is there any possibility of concurrent access to the database?

Answer (score 0):

If passenger.id is auto-incrementing you will can proceed as follows:

- insert other_info into passenger id
- retrieve the passenger id using a last_row function or select where other_info = 'other_info'
- insert into ticket using the passenger id just retrieved

If the passenger.id is not auto-incrementing you can proceed as follows:

- select max(id)+1 from passenger and store it in id_variable
- insert into passenger id_variable, other_info
- insert into ticket using id_variable as passenger_id

NB: If the table is not auto-incrementing you could still use the first system using a sub-query to calculation max(id) + 1 and then retrieve it but this does not seem as efficient as the second system.